# Trigger on Account child object not firing

Tags: apex

I have this trigger on an Account child object (Group_Name__c) and it's  supposed to email a csv file with the selected records whenever the trigger fires.
After it's all said and done I need to update the Priced__c field to true to prevent the same records from being queried again when the trigger fires - and that's why I'm creating a 'new' instance for the Group_Name__c for the update operation.
The boolean property is an attempt to avoid recursivness inherent in after update triggers.
I'm cognizant of the precariousness of having all your logic in a trigger but I'm trying to get it working first so please bear with.

Problem: trigger not firing and so no email being generated.

```
trigger PrepAccountsReadyForPricing on Group_Name__c (after insert, after update){

List<Account> actList = new List<Account>();
List<Group_Name__c> grpList = new List<Group_Name__c>();
public static boolean isExecuting = false;

public static void updateValues(){
    if(isExecuting){
        return;
    }
    isExecuting = true;

    for(Group_Name__c g: Trigger.new){
        if(g.Complete_Account__c == True && g.Group_ID__c != Null && g.Priced__c == false){
            actList.add(new Account(Id = g.Client_Account__c));
            grpList.add(new Group_Name__c(Id = g.Id, Priced__c = true));
        }
    }
    if(actList != null && !actList.isEmpty()){

        String headerString = 'SF_ACCT_ID,CarrierID,AccountID,GroupID,Group Name,Eff_Date,Account Name,\n';

        for(Account a: actList){
            String finalString = '';
            String recordString = '';
            for(Group_Name__c g : a.Group_Plans__r){
                String myDate = g.Group_Effective_Date__c.format();

                recordString = a.Id + ',' + a.Carrier_s_ID__c + ',' +  a.Account_ID__c + ',' + g.Group_ID__c + ',' + g.Name + ',' +  myDate + ',' + '"'+ a.Name + '"'+ '\n';
                finalString = finalString + recordString;
            }
            finalString = headerString + finalString;

            Date myDate = Date.Today();
            String sDate = String.valueOf(myDate).replaceAll('-', '');

            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment csvAtt = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(finalString);
            String csvName = a.Id + '_' + sDate + '.csv';
            csvAtt.setFileName(csvName);
            csvAtt.setBody(csvBlob);

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new List<String>{'xxx@mail.com'};
            String subject = 'group ready for pricing';

            email.setSubject(subject);
            email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            email.setSaveAsActivity(False);
            email.setPlainTextBody('pricing');
            email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{csvAtt});

            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] result = Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});

            }
        }
        update grpList;
    }
}
```

Comment: please note http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61371/static-variables-defined-in-a-trigger re static variables in trigger vs class

Comment: So when you say it is not firing arrow you saying that nothing in the trigger is being evaluated? If so make sure the trigger is active. Also, are you actually updating the correct record. I also do not see the trigger definition in this code.