# The code block of a trigger cannot contain the static keyword.Can elaborate the statement

Tags: apex

Apex  trigger can be declared with below code:

```
Trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert){
      static count=0;
}
```

Does the statements means the trigger cannot contain static blocks
Eg;

```
Trigger AccountTrigger on Account(before insert){
       Static{
           //code goes here
       }
}
```

Comment: This is a very easy thing to test. What happens when you try?

Answer (score 4):

That's correct. You can declare and use `static` variables in a trigger, but you cannot use `static` initializer blocks. See [Static and Instance Methods, Variables, and Initialization Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm), which notes another critical caveat about declaring statics within the body of a trigger:

> A static variable defined in a trigger doesn’t retain its value between different trigger contexts within the same transaction, such as between `before insert` and `after insert` invocations. Instead, define the static variables in a class so that the trigger can access these class member variables and check their static values.

Although it's *legal* to declare statics in a trigger body, generally, it's better to place these statics in a trigger handler class. You're also able to use static initializer blocks in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Body of a Trigger can have a Static Keyword. However, in each trigger execution context, Value of the Static Variable won't be retained.
If you want the values of the Static Value to be retained ( as we do to avoid recursive trigger calls), put the static variable in the class.
Check this- [Static variables defined in a trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61371/static-variables-defined-in-a-trigger)